# Make media query take priority over function

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I am trying to make my navigation bar responsive but I am having issues making an image (our logo) appear and disappear when desired.

First of all the default is that the navigation bar has our standard logo displayed and the alternative one hidden:

Then when moving onto a smaller screen I am using a media query to change the color of the navigation bar, hide one logo, show another logo and add a hamburger menu.

Since I found that clicking the hamburger menu, and viewing the links in block display, the alternative logo sat in the way of the first link. So I used a function to hide it (triggered upon clicking on the hamburger menu)

So far so good, clicking on the hamburger menu toggles the logo appearing and disappearing. However, if you collapse the menu without going to another page the function toggles the logo on again - which is fine until you resize the page and make it larger. Then the logo just sits in the way and isn't made to disappear by the media query.

I have tried using `!important` tags but honestly at a bit of a loss of how to do this final step. Any feedback would be much appreciated!

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Style/Basic Styling.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="page">
    <div id="page_container">


        <!--Nav Bar  Start -->
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">


            <img id="CElogo" src="https://imgur.com/gallery/Zmuzg62" alt="CE logo" title="CE logo" >
            <img id="CElogoNoTextID" class="CElogoNoText" src="https://i.imgur.com/Kr3ACDH.jpg" alt="CE logo No Text" title="CE logo No Text" >

            <a href="http://localhost:63342/untitled/Home Page/Blog/Blog.html">Blog</a>
            <a href="http://localhost:63342/untitled/Home Page/Pricing/Pricing.html">Pricing</a>

            <a id="homeNav" class="homeNavClass" href="http://localhost:63342/untitled/Home Page/Climate Edge.html">Home</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>


            <script>
                function myFunction() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
                    if (x.className === "topnav") {
                        x.className += " responsive";
                    } else {
                        x.className = "topnav";
                    }

                    var y = document.getElementById("CElogoNoTextID");
                    if (y.style.display === "none" ) {
                        y.style.display = "block";
                    } else {
                        y.style.display = "none";
                    }




                }


            </script>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
#page {
    margin:0;
    background:none;
    overflow:auto;
}
#page_container {
    margin:0 0px;
}

#HeaderImage {
    width: 100%;

    line-height:1px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.topnav {

    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    background: none;

}

#homeNav{
    display:none; !important
}

.topnav a {
    float: right;
    color: black;

    padding: 25px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;


    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 26.4px;
}
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}


.topnav img {
    width: 130px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    position:absolute;
    overflow: auto;
}

#CElogoNoTextID {

    display: none;
}

.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

#DataToAction {
    width: 30vw;
    margin-left: 35vw;
    margin-right: 35vw;
    margin-top: 5vw;
    position:absolute;    
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px)and (max-width: 1000px) {

    .topnav a {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    #DataToAction{
        display:none;
    }
    .topnav img {
       display:none;
    }
    #CElogoNoTextID{
        display: none; !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #HeaderImage {
        margin-top: 80px;
    }
    #CElogoNoTextID{
        display:block;
        float:left;
        margin-top: 0px;
        width: 90px;

    }
    .topnav {
        background: #29ABE2;
    }
    .topnav a {display: none;}
    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
    #homeNav{
        float: right;
        display: block;
        color: white;
    }
    .topnav img{
        display: none;
    }
    #DataToAction{
        display:none;
    }
}

@media screen and  (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}

    .topnav.responsive a.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        color:black;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .topnav.responsive a.homeNavClass {
        display: block;
        text-align: left; !important;
    }
}
```

Please see the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dyabLrc7/)

Comment: In order to provide a helpful answer one needs to test it. In order to test it, they would need a working [mcve]. Do you genuinely expect us to deduce/guess your markup (HTML) from the selectors you posted in your question? Don't you think you're the most appropriate person to create the working example inside the question itself, using the `<>` button, pasting all relevant code to each panel and linking all required resources in order to reproduce the problem you're having?

Comment: create a fiddle or a pen then someone may have a go!

Comment: As a side-note, the only way to override `style` attribute from CSS is using `!important`. Otherwise, `style` attribute has higher specificity and therefore applies. My wild guess is you shouldn't apply styles using JavaScript at all, but, again, without a proper [mcve] I don't think I can provide more help than mere suppositions.

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't sure how to include the images so I just included the parts that I thought were relevant - I will do so now. How shall I include the images?

Comment: @Paul, You can upload inside the snippet itself, thanks to the gracious help of the guys at imgur. On the other hand, if you don't want to use your pictures, you can always use placeholders: `http://via.placeholder.com/350x150`. Just change the size in the link.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have added it now to the question - let me know if I have done something wrong. But you can see the logo remaining when you expand the browser size again.

Comment: I'll update it myself. But I do have one question. The contents of `../Style/Basic Styling.css` is what you posted under CSS? Or something else?

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the mistake. Yes, that is linking to the CSS I posted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162197/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-paulbarr).